# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime, sql-server-2005

I am adding a date as `"09/10/2014"` into the textbox and clicking the submit button but getting error as:-

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value error.

Below is my query generated while debugging:-

```
select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where 1!=1 or Current_Item_Exp_Dt = convert(datetime, '09/10/2014', 103)
```

and below is the full code:-

```
protected void btnTrack_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string whereClause = "1!=1";

    if (ddlBin.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        whereClause = whereClause + "or location_name='" + ddlBin.SelectedValue + "'";
    }
    if (ddlItem.SelectedValue != "0")
    {
        whereClause = whereClause + "or Current_Item_code='" + ddlItem.SelectedValue + "'";
    }
    if (txtBatch.Text != "")
    {
        whereClause = whereClause
            + " or Current_Item_Batch " + (ddlmathsign.SelectedValue == "Equal" ? (" = '" + txtBatch.Text + "'") : (" like '%" + txtBatch.Text + "%'"));
    }
    if (txtExpCal.Value != "")
    {
        whereClause = whereClause + "or Current_Item_Exp_Dt " + (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than" ? ">" : (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Less than" ? "<" :
                  (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Equal to" ? "=" : (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than equal to" ? ">=" : "<=")))) + "convert(datetime, '" + txtExpCal.Value + "', 103)";
    }

    if (ddlBin.SelectedValue == "0" && ddlItem.SelectedValue == "0" && txtBatch.Text == "" && txtExpCal.Value == "")
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

    else
    {
        string query = "select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where " + whereClause;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, strConnString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GrdBinStockTracker.DataSource = dt;
        GrdBinStockTracker.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**NOTE** As I am working on local condition only to test, *SQL Injection is not a matter of concern here*.

Also, Is this a issue related to different datetime. ?

Comment: sqlserver? or any other db?

Comment: Try converting `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` in your query to the `103` format too.

Comment: Make sure you have proper data in `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` column.

Comment: @Sachu: yes it is `sql-server-2005`. Sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: @MattMurdock: how to convert that ?

Comment: @DarkKnight: I am inserting date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format for `Current_Item_Exp_Dt`

Comment: your `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` is date or datetime?

Comment: @Sachu: the datatype is `varchar`

Comment: try this `convert(date,Current_Item_Exp_Dt,103) = convert(date, '09/10/2014', 103)`

Comment: @Sachu: not getting it properly.!

Comment: SQL injection concerns aside, you can still get around the whole "string problem" by using 1)a parameter of `DateTime` type and 2)a column with the correct data type (i.e. `date`).

Comment: @lc.: Thankyou sir for that information too. For current scenario how to handle it ? any suggestion

Comment: @coder can u change the datatype of `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` to date

Comment: @Sachu: i cant touch table structure, can u tell how to change in code ?

Comment: @coder what is the result u r getting for `convert(date,Current_Item_Exp_Dt,103) = convert(date, '09/10/2014', 103)`

Comment: @Sachu: I tried like this `select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where 
1!=1 or Current_Item_Exp_Dt = convert(date, '09/10/2014', 103)` and getting error as `Type date is not a defined system type.` May be i am using `sql-server-2005`

Comment: @coder `select * from WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK where 1!=1 or convert(datetime,Current_Item_Exp_Dt,103) = convert(datetime, '09/10/2014', 103)` try this

Comment: I am getting the result in the sql-server with all the respective data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97362/discussion-between-sachu-and-coder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your column is `varchar` and not able to change to `datetime`
you need to convert that column also to datetime for the condition.

Please check the below query

```
    whereClause = whereClause + "or convert(datetime,Current_Item_Exp_Dt,103) " 
    + (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than" ? ">" : 
     (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Less than" ? "<" : 
    (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Equal to" ? "=" : 
    (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than equal to" ? ">=" : "<=")))) + 
"convert(datetime, '" + txtExpCal.Value + "', 103)";
```

> If you are not sure Current_Item_Exp_Dt always contain a valid date
>   you can use below query build as per DarkNight

```
   whereClause = whereClause + "or (CASE WHEN ISDATE(Current_Item_Exp_Dt)=1 
           THEN convert(datetime,Current_Item_Exp_Dt,103)  ELSE NULL END) " 
    + (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than" ? ">" : 
     (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Less than" ? "<" : 
    (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Equal to" ? "=" : 
    (ddlAssignvalue.SelectedValue == "Greater than equal to" ? ">=" : "<=")))) + 
"convert(datetime, '" + txtExpCal.Value + "', 103)";
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the data in `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` column.

Here is a way to reproduce it.

```sql
create table #tt(dd char(10))
insert into #tt values('13/13/2014')

select 1 from #tt where dd = convert(datetime, '09/10/2014', 103)
```

You can use this query to identify records in incorrect date format.

```
SELECT Current_Item_Exp_Dt FROM WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK WHERE ISDATE(Current_Item_Exp_Dt)=0
```

This is in possible workaround. Change you `where` conidtion to..

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN ISDATE(Current_Item_Exp_Dt)=1 
               THEN Current_Item_Exp_Dt 
               ELSE NULL END) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/10/2014', 103)
```

Your final query should be

```
SELECT Current_Item_Exp_Dt 
FROM WMS_BIN_STATUS_TRACK 
WHERE 1!=1 or (CASE WHEN ISDATE(Current_Item_Exp_Dt)=1 
               THEN Current_Item_Exp_Dt 
               ELSE NULL END) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/10/2014', 103)
```

Comment: so in short, what changes do I need to make. because every time user can insert any date into the textbox and check for the result

Comment: @coder : change data type of `Current_Item_Exp_Dt` column to `date`. You should insert only valid dates into the table. Issue is not with the current input, but with the existing data in table.

Comment: i cant cahnge the datatype, instead if there is any change will in the code i can do that.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer, if possible please arrange with my code.!

Comment: @coder : I wish I could help you, but it takes time to go through C# code. I have updated answer with the final query you need to use. Hope that helps!